# The only word that is not passing the test is "almostomla."

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS on freecodecamp and am stuck on a problem. I am creating a palindrome checker. My code almost works. However, there is only one word that is not passing the test and that is almostomla. It is not a palindrome yet my code returns true.  I have tried several things. Even rewrote the code and used the while loop but nothing seems to help. There is a solution at the freeCodecamp web but I have written the code in a different way and am unable to figure my mistake out.

Here is my code.

```js
let reversedStr = [];

function palindrome(str) {
  let d = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "").toLowerCase();
  for (let i = d.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversedStr.push(d[i]);
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
    if (reversedStr[j] == d[j]) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
console.log(palindrome("almostomla"));
```

Comment: Your `reversedStr` variable should be declared **inside** the function.

Comment: Also your function returns from inside the iteration, which is wrong; it will only test one character.

Comment: remove the char comparison and replace with return reversedStr==str;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `if (reversedStr[j] == d[j]) {return true;` returns as soon as the character matches at both the index. It does not check rest of the characters.

In fact you can just return as soon as the character in both index does not match.

Also note the `reversedStr` has to be inside the function. Else it will contain previous values

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  let reversedStr = [];
  let d = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "").toLowerCase();
  for (let i = d.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversedStr.push(d[i]);
  }
  
  for (let j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
    if (reversedStr[j] !== d[j]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true
}
console.log(palindrome("almostomla"));
console.log(palindrome("1221"));
```

Comment: I didn't pay attention to this at all. I was returning true as soon as the first word matched and that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns "true" or "false" after first match - it checks that 'a' is equal  to 'a' and returns true.

You can return "false" **from inside** of cycle only if you found duplicated letter else return true **after** the cycle ends.